# With Tiles, is there a way to reduce my two JSPs into one JSP?

Tags: tiles

I'm using Tiles for the first time.  Trying to layout my JSP pages in my Spring MVC project.

Please take a look at what I'm doing and let me know if this is the "correct" way to do it ... my specific question is at the bottom ...

I have the file structured like this ... folder `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/layouts/` contains ...

standard.jsp

```
// ...
<html>
    <title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title"/></title>
// ... LOTS OF HTML ...
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="header"/>
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="body"/>
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer"/>
// ... LOTS OF HTML
</html>
// ...
```

tiles.xml

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="standardLayout" template="/WEB-INF/layouts/standard.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="My Directory" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/layouts/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

And my viewable JSPs are in folder `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/` which contains ...

tiles.xml

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="home" extends="standardLayout">
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

home.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"%>

<tiles:insertDefinition name="home">
    <tiles:putAttribute name = "body" value="/WEB-INF/views/home-body.jsp"/>
</tiles:insertDefinition>
```

home-body.jsp

```
<div>
// LOTS OF HTML FOR THE BODY OF THE HOME PAGE
</div>
```

QUESTIONS: I'd like to just have one `home.jsp` but it looks like I have to pull the body content (and any other content) from a separate file.  Is there an appropriate way to simplify `home.jsp` and `home-body.jsp` into one file, or am I actually doing this all correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your tiles.xml, standard.jsp and home.jsp as below,

**tiles.xml**

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="home" extends="standardLayout">
       <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp"></put-attribute>
    </definition>        
</tiles-definitions>
```

**standard.jsp**

```
 <html>
   <title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title"/></title>
   <header>
       <tiles:insertAttribute name="header"/>
   </header>
   <body>
       <tiles:insertAttribute name="body"/>
   </body>
   <footer>
       <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer"/>
   </footer>
 </html>
```

**home.jsp**

```
<!-- Actual body content goes here.. -->    
<%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"%>    
<p>The content of the home page.</p>
```